# Default value of a type using Mono Cecil

Tags: .net, reflection, mono, mono.cecil

I have a method to return default value of any Type based on Reflection like below

```
private object getDefault(Type type) 
{
    object defaultValue = null;
    //I have some specific logics here
    defaultValue = getCustomDefaultValues(type);

    //Value types
    if(defaultValue == Type.Missing && type.IsValueType)  
    {       
         defaultValue=  Activator.CreateInstance(type);  
    }
    //All other types including Ref.        
    return defaultValue == Type.Missing ? "null" : defaultValue;
}
```

Now I am moving to Mono Cecil from classic reflection. So "Type" will become "TypeDefinition". Problem is that **Activator.CreateInstance(type);** won't work with TypeDefinition. So is there any other ways to find the default value of any type? or any existing easy way to get the default value of a Type in Cecil?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Mono Cecil is for manipulating some external assembly, that most likely isn't currently loaded. If it isn't loaded, you can't create an instance of a type from that assembly. If it is loaded, why are you trying to use Mono Cecil in the first place?

Comment: Really, I don't want to load the assembly. I only need to browse the assembly and based on that information I am generating some new files with code. Those C# files may contains same types of this base assembly. If those types are passing as parameter , my code geneartion tool to provide some default value during runtime. So if we have a TypeDefinition, some how this default value to be generated during run time. It's not mandatory to use "CreateInstance" and looking some way a genaral logic for all Types.

Comment: “my code geneartion tool to provide some default value during runtime” I really don't understand what you mean by that. Either you're generating code or you're working with it at runtime, I don't see why would you want to do both. And if you don't want to load the assembly, then you simply can't create an instance of a type from that assembly.

Comment: Allright. I am doing an automated unittesting tool which will generate all test method code bases inlcuding some mocking commands. So our developers to spend less time for TDD as they will have all skelton. For generating automated unit test methods, I need to browse and only browse the corresponding assemblies for just information about external types, internal types etc...  Is that making sense? If I read a method like "Method1(Type1 obj)", I will generate a test code by passing a default value of "Type1" for developers to replace it with a valid value.

Comment: So, you generate code and then immeditely execute it? In that case, can't you generate code to instantiate that object, instead of instantiating it direcly? I think that would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Instantiating is not needed. I want Default value of a Type by chekcing whether it's Value, Ref or Generic etc... My developers will replace those default value with a real one. Instantiating  is the way used to attain it before cecil, but may not valid here. Goal is to get the Default value of any Type returned by cecil so that I can use that value in my code generation

Comment: Maybe now I'm starting to understand. I think you shouldn't get the default value at all (which, in the case of value types, *is* instantiating). `Type` (or its equivalent in Cecil) should be sufficient to do your checks, look at properties like `IsValueType` or `IsGenericType`.

Comment: Mean time, I am here publishing the code which I am now proceeding with and also expecting comments on any flaw on this approach you people are seeing. private object getDefault(TypeDefinition type)
  {

   object defaultValue = null;
   defaultValue = getCustomDefaultValues(type);

   //Value types
   if (defaultValue == Type.Missing && type.IsValueType)
   {
       **defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type.FullName)) ;**
   }